# In the Django admin, how can I set up searching profiles by username?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like to be able to search user profiles by username in the Django admin. Essentially, in admin.py, I'd be doing something like:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   search_fields = ['username']
```

But this won't work since `user` is a foreign key in the my usual user profile set up.

Is there a quick way to achieve this without having to add a `username` field to my UserProfile model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['user__username']
```

assuming the name of your field that is foreignkey is `user`